# Remove duplicates from TWO columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Good Morning stackoverflownians,

I have a very big table with duplicates on two columns. Means that if numbers on row a are duplicated in col1 and col2 on row b, I should keep only row a :

```
## table_1 
col1    col2

1           10
1           10
1           10
1           11
1           11
1           12
2           20
2           20
2           21
2           21


# should return this tbl without duplication

col1    col2

1           10
1           11
1           12
2           20
2           21
```

My previous code account only for col1, and I don't know how to query this on two coluns :

```
CREATE TABLE temp LIKE db.table_1;
INSERT INTO temp SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE 1 GROUP BY col1;
DROP TABLE table_1;
ALTER TABLE temp RENAME table_1;
```

So I thought about that :

```
CREATE TABLE temp LIKE db.table_1;
INSERT INTO temp(col1,col2)
  SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2 FROM table_1;

then drop and rename..
```

But I'm not sure it's gonna work and MySQL tend to be unstable, if it takes too long I will have to stop the query and that my crash the server again .. T.T

We have 200,000,000 rows and all of them have at least one duplicate..

Any Suggestion of code ? :) 
Also .. How long would it take ? minutes or hours ?

Comment: Check the first answer of this question; it may help you to find out the solution; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105618/how-to-get-only-repeated-records-in-a-table

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT DISTINCT` is the right way to do this.  If you're having stability issues, just take your site/system offline until the query completes.  Plan the downtime in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already know quite a ways :)

you can try this also

Use `INSERT IGNORE` rather than `INSERT`. If a record doesn't duplicate an existing record, MySQL inserts it as usual. If the record is a duplicate, the IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to discard it silently without generating an error.

Read from existing table and then write on a new table using `INSERT IGNORE`. This way you can control insert process depending on your resource usage.

When using INSERT IGNORE and you do have key violations, MySQL does NOT raise a warning!!!

Comment: Thanks! So If I do    INSERT IGNORE INTO temp(col1,col2) SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2 FROM table_1 ==> Is it faster than just insert into etc.. ?

Comment: INSERT IGNORE INTO temp(col1,col2) SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2 FROM table_1

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing how this performs.  Sounds very promising.

Comment: I havent done any benchmarking for this but I can suggest if you are already doing this you can try this out. In a fixed resource boundary like cpu , io usage you can come up with some benchmarks for different ways as suggested by others also. I am sure people will be interested and it will be helpful for many.

Answer (score 0):

the distinct clause is the way to go, but it will take a while to run on that many records.  I'd add an ID column that is autoincrment, and is your pk.  Then you can run the deduplicate in stages that won't time out.

Good luck and HTH
-- Joe

Comment: OH WAIT !! I REALLY WANTED TO DO THAT : I tried to add the ID PK on col1 but it shows an error coz there's duplicates.. ? Should I add a columnd ID AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ?

Comment: OH I misread... If I had a column ID AUTO_INCREMENT PK, ... how is that gonna be faster ?